# Network traffic tarification while using Gmail API

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I have a question about billing of Internet traffic when using the Gmail API. Is there a difference between hosting an application on Google cloud service or another cloud service (Amazon, for example)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because its about billing and not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not bill for requests to the Gmail API.

In terms of egress traffic, if you're hosting on AWS, you'll pay Amazon for traffic to Google. There is no charge for egress traffic from GCP to Google APIs. Unless you're migrating a huge amount of data, I'd be surprised to see that add up to much.

Also be mindful [Gmail API Quota Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota) and [Gmail per-user sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en).